# how to make connection between visual studio project and unit test project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have big C# solution.
I added to this solution an unit testing project.

I want to make somehow a connection between the unit testing and all the other project -
what I mean is I want to make a automation that will run the unit testing on the end of the project build and if there will be any test fail => the project build will show fail

How to do it ?

Comment: http://highoncoding.com/Articles/398_Using_Post_Build_Event_to_Execute_Unit_Tests.aspx, https://gist.github.com/joelbyler/4042597

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio you can select option presented below, but it will not cause a build error when Unit Tests will fail.

[image: Visual Studio]